# Regular Expression to remove contents in string

Tags: asp.net, regex, c#-4.0

I have a string as below:

```
4s: and in this <em>new</em>, 5s: <em>year</em> everybody try to make our planet clean and polution free.
```

Replace string:

```
4s: and in this <em>new</em>, <em>year</em> everybody try to make our planet clean and polution free.
```

what i want is ,if string have two `<em>` tags , and if gap between these two `<em>` tags is of just one word and also , format of that word will be of `ns:` (n is any numeric value 0 to 4 char. long). then i want to remove `ns:` from that string. while keeping punctuation marks('?', '.' , ',',) between two `<em>` as it is.

also i like to add note that. input string may or may not have punctuation marks between these two `<em>` tags.

My regular expression as below

```
Regex.Replace(txtHighlight, @"</em>.(\s*)(\d*)s:(\s*).<em", "</em> <em");
```

Hope it is clear to my requirement.
How can I do this using regular expressions?

Comment: Please update the title of the question to something more descriptive of the question.

Comment: not really sure what you're trying to do yet.  you have these span tags in your regex that aren't in your string.  The regex doesn't match arbitrary text at any point, so it seems your starting point isn't very close to the desired solution either.  Help us understand a bit better what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to do? From what you have, it looks like all you want to achieve is to remove "5s: " from the first string to get the 2nd. Is that what you want? If not, please show us the `before` and `after` strings you hope to get. The more examples, the better.

Comment: There're no `<span>` in your string, so your regex doesn't match.

Comment: sorry guys for confusion.. i edited my post , hope its clear to understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you need, but how about:

```
Regex.Replace(txtHighlight, @"</em>(.)\s*\d+s:\s*(.)<em", "</em>$1$2<em");
```

Comment: thanks , @M42 for your reply... i found , still i haven't explained my question very well. so it found confusing to you all. 

aslo i like to add note , that my regular expression is not correct. but my input and my wanted output are correct. i add some markers in my post for making it clear.

i again editing my question. i hope it make clear to my requirement.

Comment: hey @M42... my prob is solved with help of your suggestion , thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to take out the `4s 5s` bit you could do something like this:

```
Regex.Replace(txtHighlight, @"\s\d\:", "");
```

This will match a space followed by a digit followed by a colon.

If that's not what you're after, my apologies.  I hope it might help :)

Comment: hi... thanks for your reply.... but i dont want to replace all `4s:` , `5s:` , but only that which have <em> consecutive , and have only `ns:` or one more char between them. and in that i need to keep other char. than `ns:` as it is.